# Laravel, get id on request from input blade

Tags: php, laravel

I have many `<input>` like this:

```
<input type="number" id="{!! $item->id !!}" name="function_count[]" value="{{ $item->value }}"
```

In Controller, I can get an array of each input value, with:

```
$inputs = $request->input('function_count');
```

But also I need to get the `id="{!! $item->id !!}"` in the same array, because I need the data related (id and value) in the Controller. How could I do that?

Comment: I *think* you can put `$item->id` in `name="function_count[]"`, like `name="function_count[{{ $item->id }}]"`, and `$request->input('function_count')` should be an associative array. If you loop `$inputs`, like `foreach($inputs AS $id => $input)`, `$id` should be the value of `$item->id`, while `$input` would be `$item->value`. Otherwise, send the `id` in `value`, and query for `$item` on the backend.

Comment: You are my Jeffrey Way right now. Flawless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass two values via one input field. However, to achieve what you want, you can have different approaches.

**Recommended Approach:**

I am assuming, your `function_count[]` hasMany `id`. Therefore, you can create associative array as your input `name` like this:

```
<input type="number" name="function_count[{!! $item->id !!}]" value="" />
```

Later you can,

```
$inputs = $request->input('function_count');
foreach($inputs as $id=>$value){
    // $id being the content of $item->id
    // $value being the content of value=""
}
```

**Approach #2:**

If your `id="{!! $item->id !!}"` has client-side importance and you want to keep the attribute, you can also combine the data right before the form is submitted like this:

```
$("form").submit( function () {
    $(this).find("input[type=number]").each(function(){
        $(this).val($(this).attr("id") + ":" + $(this).val());
    });
    return;
});
```

Later you can,

```
$inputs = $request->input('function_count');
foreach($inputs as $input){
    $contents = explode(":",$input);
    // $contents[0] being the content of $item->id
    // $contents[1] being the content of value=""
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did the first way, as @Tim Lewis commented.